# Call functions on children components that are part of an ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a parent component that gets a list of objects. The parent component's corresponding html file creates several children components based on that list using an ngFor. How do you go about calling a function in EACH of the children components?

Here is my parent component Typescript file (edited for clarity):

```
export class HomeComponent {
    childObjects: Array<ChildObject> = [];

    constructor() {
        this.childObjectService.getChildObjects()
            .subscribe(res => {
            this.childObjects = res;
        }); 
    }
}
```

and here is my parent component HTML:

```
<childObjectComponent *ngFor="let childObject of childObjects">
    <!--I want to call a function on each of these childObjectComponent template objects-->
<childObjectComponent>
```

So if all of my ChildObject component class has a function called AddNumbers(), how would I call it on all of my ChildObjects?

Comment: Each component is constructed separately, so you should just be able to call the method inside of the ngOnInit in the child component.  Have you tried this?

Comment: Where would you call that function?

Comment: @JSess That will work, but I don't want to call the function inside an ngOnInit. The full version of my code works like this: The parent component is created along with all of the children components. The user is presented with UI buttons. One of the UI buttons brings up a list of values that the user can choose. When the user clicks one of those values, I would like to call a function in each of the children components.

Comment: @acdcjunior Are you referring to JSess's response? It seems like I need to call the function (that exists on the children object) from the parent component/html.

Comment: Yes, but where? At the view/template? At the TS?

Comment: I'm fairly new to html/typescript. Isn't it standard to call functions from parent to child using the child template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by creating a list of objects associated with the childObjectComponent template objects. Basically, whenever a childObjectComponent is created, I use the ngAfterViewInit() method provided by Angular to emit the object to my parent component. The parent component adds the emitted object to a list it maintains.

For example, if 5 childObjectComponent template objects are created, then 5 objects will be emitted to the parent component. The parent component will add those 5 to a list. I can then do whatever I want to do with those template objects using a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to have a DOM element for each of your childObjects (`ngFor`) where you can execute a function on the object when you click the element:

```
export class HomeComponent {
    childObjects: Array<ChildObject> = [];

    constructor() {
        this.childObjectService.getChildObjects()
            .subscribe(res => {
            this.childObjects = res;
        }); 
    }

    doSomething(childObject : ChildObjectType) {
      /* Do something with child object */
    }
}
```

```
<childObjectComponent *ngFor="let childObject of childObjects">
  <div (click)="doSomething(childObject)">{{childObject.text}}</div>
<childObjectComponent>
```

**Edit:** Do something on all the objects:

```
export class HomeComponent {
    childObjects: Array<ChildObject> = [];

    constructor() {
        this.childObjectService.getChildObjects()
            .subscribe(res => {
            this.childObjects = res;
        }); 
    }

    doSomethingOnAll() {
      this.childObjects.forEach((child) => {
        /* do something on each child object */
      } 
    }
}
```

```
<childObjectComponent *ngFor="let childObject of childObjects">
  <div (click)="doSomethingOnAll()">{{childObject.text}}</div>
<childObjectComponent>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know how to execute a function on a single object, but I would like to execute a function on ALL of the childObjects at once.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The function I would like to call lives on the childObjectComponent template object, not the childObjects array. I'm simply using the childObjects array to tell my html how many childObjectComponents to create.

Comment: The childObject object are simply created using a model file. I came up with a solution below as a separate answer. I'm not sure how "clean" of an idea it is.

Answer (score 1):

One way to have the parent call methods in a child is with @ViewChild. It is documented here in the Angular docs:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild

Note that in the parent you have to wait for ngAfterViewInit, which allows the children to render themselves.

That entire page lists out several different ways for components to talk to each other.